# Vaadin and Apache Netbeans 12

Tags: vaadin, netbeans-12

I'm new in Vaadin and I'm trying to run the demo project from the QuickStart tutorial. I'm using Netbeans 12.0 and when trying to run the project I get a window with a Select Main Class for Execution, and there is no class to select.

I've seen that for Netbeans 8.2 there was a Vaadin plugin, but I can't find it for version 12.0

What I'm missing?

Kind Regards,

Rafa

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why you still use Netbeans 12, but the steps below should also work for v12. (I'm on Netbeans 17)

I assume that you have the pom.xml from maven, which you are using in netbeans.
For Vaadin 10+ versions, there is no longer the need for the netbeans plugin, (That one was required/helpfull) for compiling the widgetsets, which you don't have any longer in Vaadin 10+

To run the project, it depends if you use the spring boot or a non-springboot project.
The spring boot project should be started via main class, if that does not work, please provide some stack trace/error logs etc.

For non - spring boot projects, you have to tell netbeans to run in on a specific server/servlet container.

For this go to the project properties -> Run and select the correct tomcat instance and complete the other fields.
For Vaadin  10-23 it must be a tomcat 9.x instance, for Vaadin 24 it must be a tomcat 10.x instance

For example like this:
[image]